# Why is my JavaScript If statement not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I have been trying for a good minute to figure out why my if statement never triggers. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
var clickcounter = 0;
var buttonclicker = document.getElementById("buttonclicker");

function unblur() {
    clickcounter = clickcounter + 1;
    console.log(clickcounter);
}

if (clickcounter === 1) {
    buttonclicker.textContent = "Unlock More";
    alert(clickcounter);
}
```

the variable clickcounter will be equal to or over 1. I at first tried using if (clickcounter => 1) and also tried if (clickcounter > 0) but none of this worked. What am I doing wrong?
Here is a codepen of the whole thing: https://codepen.io/sage379/pen/JyppZv

Comment: You set `clickcounter` to 0 and then check if it's equal to 1.  It's not 1, it's 0.  Because it was just set to 0.

Comment: What calls `unblur`?

Comment: unblur is called by an onClick function, I left a lot of the code out, my mistake. https://codepen.io/sage379/pen/JyppZv is a codepen of the whole thing

Comment: @user3161849: Yes, but `unblur` isn't called until something else calls it.  Whereas your `if` statement executes *immediately*.  Did you mean to put the `if` statement in the `unblur` function?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code example, `unblur()` never gets called so `clickcounter` remains `0`.

Comment: and even if `unblur` does get called, the conditional has already tested the state of `clickcounter` so its too late.

Comment: @Octopus assuming that the code is written as it appears in the question.  Sometimes users copy a few lines here, a few lines there, and put it all together in the question without realizing how much context they're throwing out.  This was how I interpreted the code in the question.

Comment: I should've specified, unblur() is called.. and I know the variable is changed because I made it console.log the value of clickcounter.. here is a codepen of it: https://codepen.io/sage379/pen/JyppZv

Comment: Sure, you change clickcounter when you click the button but you never run that if statement again after that. Your code does the following:

Set clickcounter to 0, check if clickcounter === 1. Then your function changes click counter and that's all your code does. You could call a function from within unblur that checks if clickcounter === 1 but currently you just increment the value and do nothing with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that once you increment `clickcounter`, you never check if it's changed. That check is performed once in your script, immediately after setting `clickcounter = 0`.

Here is an example where I've wrapped that check in a new function called `checkClickCounter()`. This function is called in `unblur()` each time it is called by your button click. I changed your if statement back to `>=` but since you're incrementing by one it will always return true after one click using `===` so this change doesn't matter in your current code.

```
var clickcounter = 0;
var buttonclicker = document.getElementById("buttonclicker");

function unblur() {
    clickcounter = clickcounter + 1;
    checkClickCounter(clickcounter);
}

function checkClickCounter(count){
    if (count >= 1) {
        buttonclicker.textContent = "Unlock More";
        //alert(clickcounter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. Let me know if i did not understand your requirement.

```
var clickcounter = 0;
var buttonclicker = document.getElementById("buttonclicker");

       function unblur() {

            clickcounter = clickcounter + 1;
            console.log(clickcounter);


             if (parseInt(clickcounter) >= 1){
                  buttonclicker.textContent = "Unlock More";

             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your if statement inside of unblur:

```
var clickcounter = 0; 
var buttonclicker = document.getElementById("buttonclicker");
function unblur() {
 clickcounter = clickcounter + 1;
 console.log(clickcounter);
 if (clickcounter === 1) {
    buttonclicker.textContent = "Unlock More"; 
    alert(clickcounter);
 }
}
```